# Comparing arrays not printing the differences

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Here is my test code:

```
$a = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"21");

$b = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"21", "Joe"=>"43");

function leo_array_diff($a, $b) {
    $map = array();
    foreach($a as $val) $map[$val] = 1;
    foreach($b as $val) unset($map[$val]);
    return array_keys($map);
}

print_r(leo_array_diff($a, $b));

echo "<br>";

print_r(array_diff($a, $b));
```

here is what it prints out:

```
Array ( [0] => 37 ) 
Array ( [Ben] => 37 )
```

---

***i'm going to be referring to the `leo_array_diff()` function:***

**First question:**

as you can see, peter is the same number so thats good. `$a` ben and `$b` ben is different. `$a` and `$b` joe is different. but it is only showing ben is different.

maybe because `$a` joe 21 is same as `$b` ben is 21? how can i change that? peter needs to correspond with peter, ben needs to correspond with ben, etc...

**Second question:**

Ben is different, yes, because 37 and 21 but in the `print_r`, it only shows `Array ( [0] => 37 )`. how can i make it show `Array ( [0] => 21 )`? How do I edit the function and not swapping the parameter when calling the function?

Comment: 1) Take a look at `array_diff_assoc()` 2) Read the documentation about `array_diff_assoc()` the order of your arguments is important!

Comment: @Rizier123 wow, that worked for the second line. what about the first line that uses the function `leo_array_diff()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have a misunderstanding of [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).

> Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

It's not returning the index `Joe` because the value `21` is in the first array.

Now, why is your function not working? Well let's go step by step.

Here's what your map is looking like after your first foreach:

```
array(
    '35' => '1',
    '37' => '1',
    '21' => '1'
)
```

Then, in your second foreach, you're looping through the array and removing the key where the value matches. So basically, you're removing the index `35` and index `21` which is why only the index 37 remains. **The real problem here is because you're not checking for the name anywhere**.

Here's an alternative to your function:

```
function leo_array_diff($a, $b) {

    $map = array();

    foreach($a as $name => $value){

        // The name is not found in the second array
        // Or the value is different from the first array
        if(!isset($b[$name]) || $b[$name] != $value)
            $map[$value] = 1;

    }

    return array_keys($map);

}
```

The `var_dump` would be:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
        int(37)
    [1]=>
        int(21)
}
```

Comment: wow ur a genius! ok, how can I return the value from the second array? for example: with ur function right now, i get this: `Array ( [0] => 37 [1] => 21 ) `. Right now, i get values 37 and 21 because they are different. How can I get the values from array 2? In this case 21 and 43?

Comment: @jasonmoqio Again as I already said in my comment above your question: **The order of your arguments is important!**

Comment: @jasonmoqio If you want the other way around, you have to reverse the order of the parameters like rizier said. However, if you want, I could change the function to return both in a subarray.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange $a and $b

print_r(leo_array_diff($b,$a));

Just swap the arrays ...the first parameter is used to display position that the difference on thus use the that array's values.

Comment: yes i know. please see the edit. How do I edit the function and not swapping the parameter when calling the function?