# Assign key to array values

Tags: php, arrays, key, associative-array

i have a function that i got from stack-overflow:-

```
function testFunction($a, $b) {
    $map = array();
    foreach($a as $name => $value){
        if(!isset($b[$name]) || $b[$name] != $value) {
            $map[$value] = 1;
        }
    }
    return array_keys($map);
}

$array1 = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"21", "Joe"=>"43");
$array2 = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"57");

print_r(testFunction($array2, $array1));
```

here is the result i get:

```
Array ( [0] => 37 [1] => 57 )
```

because the 37 in second array is different than 21 in first array... and the 57 is different than the 43.

my question is: **how can i add a key to the values? for example, I want this:**

```
Array ("Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"57");
```

Comment: Pretty much the same question was asked yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42166487/3933332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
<?php

function testFunction($a, $b) {
    $map = array();
    foreach($a as $name => $value){
        if(!isset($b[$name]) || $b[$name] != $value) {
            $map[$name] = $value; // make key value array
        }
    }
    return $map;
}

$array1 = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"21", "Joe"=>"43");
$array2 = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"57");

print_r(testFunction($array2, $array1));
```

Output:-  https://eval.in/735195

Comment: @pixie123  glad to help you. :):):)

Answer (score 0):

Short and optimized solution using `array_intersect_key` and `array_diff` functions:

```
$array1 = ["Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"21", "Joe"=>"43"];
$array2 = ["Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"57", 'I'=>0];

// getting all $array2 items with coincident keys
$common_key_items = array_intersect_key($array2, $array1);

// getting value difference between arrays with same keys 
$result = array_diff($common_key_items, $array1);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [Ben] => 37
    [Joe] => 57
)
```